# my opencv code running really slow (maybe memory leak?)

Tags: c, opencv, memory-leaks

I'm writing an image amplifier that follows the mouse.But there're some problems with it.It becomes really slow as time goes by.I think the reason may be memory leak.But I don't know where is wrong and how to get it correct.I'll be grateful if anyone could help!

This is my code:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define Radius_0 60
#define Radius_1 90

IplImage* src = 0;
IplImage* dst = 0;

void  my_mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void * param)
{
    int center_x0, center_y0;
    int center_x1, center_y1;
    if(event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE)
    {
        if(x <= 60) center_x0 = 60;
        else if(x >= src->width - 60) center_x0 = src->width - 60;
        else
            center_x0 = x;
        if(y <= 60) center_y0 = 60;
        else if(y >= src->height - 60) center_y0 = src->height - 60;
        else
            center_y0 = y;
        if(x <= 90) center_x1 = 90;
        else if(x >= dst->width - 90) center_x1 = src->width - 90;
        else
            center_x1 = x;
        if(y <= 90) center_y1 = 90;
        else if(y >= src->height - 90) center_y1 = src->height - 90;
        else
            center_y1 = y;

        IplImage* tmp = cvCreateImage(CvSize(Radius_0*3, Radius_0*3), src->depth, src->nChannels);
        cvZero(tmp);
        CvPoint p0 = cvPoint(center_x0-Radius_0, center_y0-Radius_0);
                CvPoint p1 = cvPoint(center_x0+Radius_0, center_y0+Radius_0);
                cvSetImageROI(src,cvRect(p0.x,p0.y,p1.x-p0.x,p1.y-p0.y));
                cvResize(src, tmp);
        cvResetImageROI(src);

        cvZero(dst);
        dst = cvCloneImage(src);
        uchar* DstData = (uchar *)dst->imageData;
        uchar* TmpData = (uchar *)tmp->imageData;
        int DstStep = dst->widthStep/sizeof(uchar);
        int TmpStep = tmp->widthStep/sizeof(uchar);
                int channels = dst -> nChannels;
        for(int i = center_y1-Radius_1; i < center_y1+Radius_1; ++ i)
        {
            for(int j = center_x1-Radius_1; j < center_x1+Radius_1; ++ j)
            {
                int r = (i - center_y1)*(i - center_y1) + (j - center_x1)*(j - center_x1);
                if(r <= Radius_1*Radius_1)
                {
                    int m = i + Radius_1 - center_y1;
                    int n = j + Radius_1 - center_x1;
                    DstData[i*DstStep+j*channels+0] = TmpData[m*TmpStep+n*channels+0];
                    DstData[i*DstStep+j*channels+1] = TmpData[m*TmpStep+n*channels+1];
                    DstData[i*DstStep+j*channels+2] = TmpData[m*TmpStep+n*channels+2];
                }
            }
        }
        cvShowImage("dst",dst); 
        cvReleaseImage(&tmp);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    if(argc != 2){
        return -1;
    }
    src = cvLoadImage(argv[1], 1);
    dst = cvCloneImage(src);
    cvNamedWindow("dst", 1);
    cvShowImage("dst",dst);
        cvSetMouseCallback("dst", my_mouse_callback, 0 );
        while(1){
                if(cvWaitKey(15) == 27)
                        break;
        }
        cvDestroyAllWindows();
        cvReleaseImage(&src);
    cvReleaseImage(&dst);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: please **DO NOT** use opencv's venerable c-api, but the c++ one (cv::Mat). it's no wonder, that you got memleaks like this.

Comment: @berak Thanks,berak! But I'm wondering why memory leak happens?I've used cvReleaseImage() in my codes....

Comment: As @berak said, please don't use the old C API anymore. I don't know, but I suspect that `dst = cvCloneImage(src)` does not release the previous content of `dst`, so if you do want to persist with this, insert a `cvReleaseImage(&dst)` before that call if `dst` is not null.

Comment: Thanks,@RogerRowland !

Comment: That's it!!!!!!!Thanks a lot!!@RogerRowland

Comment: Regarding this line: `#include <stdio.h>`, the posted code is written for C++, not C.  so remove the 'c' tag and add the 'c++' tag.   The proper header file to #include in c++ is <cstdio>

Comment: as you can see from the posted code, do not use tabs when indenting.  because (as easily visible in the posted code), every word processor/editor has the tab widths/tab stops set differently.   Also, for readability, suggest separating code blocks (if, else, while, do...while, switch/case/default) by a blank line

Comment: there are several 'magic' numbers in the code.  Such as 60, 3, 90.  'magic' numbers make the code very difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using #define statements or a enum to give the numbers meaningful names and use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: running the code with `valgrind` will expose any memory leaks and where they are located.

Comment: When writing c++ code, it is much better to use `const type name=value;` statements than to use #define statements.